# Bar chart with Matplotlib gives excessive bar width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Matplotlib and I'm trying to plot a simple bar chart with the code below

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
y = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
plt.bar(X, y, align='edge', width = 0.8, edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(X)
plt.show()
```

I have no idea why I obtain a graph like this. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib is doing exactly as told - plot a bar of height 0.8 and width 0.8 starting at x=0.4 (and therefore occupying space until x=1.2) and one bar of height 0.2, starting at x=0.5 and ranging to x=1.3

This looks odd because a width of 0.8 is excessive for your scale: your data ranges from 0-1, and 0.8 takes up 80% of that, resulting in horizontally stretched bars. Setting the bar width to 0.1 results in a more aesthetically pleasing result

[image: Adjusted width]

Comment: Thanks! Are you suggesting that when the x coordinates of the bars are numeric, I should take the scale into consideration? It seems that if I set X to an array of strings, matplotlib will automatically ajust the graph.

Comment: For string labels on the x axis, matplotlib will map them to numeric values along the lines of `X[0] -> 0, X[1] -> 1, X[2] -> 2` etc and employ the 0.8 default width from there (which separates the bars nicely on that scale)